# jquery Index() not working properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/dmhsfds4/

basically index gives -1 all the time, even though there is element present with class `.current` when the function is ran.

Is it a bug?

```
<p class="current" id="one">Point 1</p>
<p id="two">Point 2</p>
<p id="three">Point 3</p>
<p id="four">Point 4</p>
<p id="five">Point 5</p>
<p id="six">Point 6</p>
<p id="seven">Point 7</p>
```

---

```
var p = $('p');
var i = 0;
setInterval(function(){
    i +=1;
    if (i>6) i=0;

    console.log(p.index('.current'));

    p.removeClass('current').eq(i).addClass('current');
},1000);
```

Comment: Your HTML is an integral part of this question. Please put all relevant code directly in the question instead of making your question dependent on off-site resources.

Comment: This is one of the worst examples of jQuery's API. It's completely ambiguous and arguably more intuitive the way you interpreted its meaning. But jQuery just loves overloading methods with different behavior. They would do better to have differently named methods, like `element.getIndexIn(collection)` and `collection.indexOf(element)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the `p.index()` to `$('p.current').index()`. `p.index()` is just checking the first `p` not each one.
Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/depperm/dmhsfds4/1/).

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned in the [jQuery docs](https://api.jquery.com/index/#index-element),

The function `.index()` takes an element as a parameter like this.

```
p.index($('.current'))
```

and **NOT** the class or id like this.

<strike>`p.index('.current')`</strike> **OR** <strike>`p.index('#someId')`</strike>

Here is the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dmhsfds4/2/)

Comment: The docs show that it *does* accept a selector string but it's behavior differs when you do that.